# python udf in redshift - support for nested udf

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

I am trying to implement a nested udf in redshift.

```
select 
     custom_function(custom_function('', column1), column2) 
from 
     table1
```

But it says nested udfs are not supported. can someone help me here?

Tried using the python library approach mentioned in the answer and its shown below!!

```
class f_string:
   def __init__(self, current_value, key, value):
   self.current_value = current_value
   self.key = key
   self.value = value

def f_make_json(self):
   import json
   current_value = json.loads(self.current_value)
   self.value.replace('"', '\"')
   current_value[self.key] = self.value
   return (json.dumps(current_value))
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to organize the UDF that you'd like to nest as a Python library and import that library to your cluster, here is the [instruction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html#udf-importing-custom-python-library-modules)

Comment: not sure I understand how they are supposed to be nested and what exactly did you do in terms of library bundling

Comment: i am trying to create a json string. something like this make_json(make_json('{}', 'key1', 'value1'), 'key2', 'value2') which will return {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'}

Comment: ah, it's the same function nested... I thought it's different functions nested. Can you try the first function in a subquery and the second function in the outer query?

Comment: there could be more than 2 variables. so having multiple subqueries wont be the ideal solution here!!

Comment: after all, why don't you just build your json using concatenation operator? I was always doing this and it was pretty easy and clean with proper formatting of the code like every key/value pair on a new line and proper indentation for embedded objects

Comment: yes. thats what i am doing now. wanted to create a function so that it can be used in multiple scripts and dont have to worry about formatting!!